# Question about accessing object method with vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am new to c++ and I have an assignement on vector/iterators. I ran into a problem that I was able to solve by searching on the internet but unfortunately the forums I visited only provided with the solution and did not explain why it works. Here's the problem I had:

```
std::vector::<Student*>::iterator iter;
for (iter = v_students.begin(); iter != v_students.end(); iter++)
{
     iter*->doStuff(); // Gave me a compile error
}
```

I tried a long time to solve that error without success until I found on a forum someone suggesting this instead:

```
(*iter)->doStuff;
```

Placing the * in front of the iterator and putting () around it seems to do the trick but I'd like to understand why. Thanks !

Comment: What did you expect `iter*->` to do? The unary operators like the "dereference operator" (`*`) must always be before their operand.

Comment: the way to get the value designated by the iterator is to dereference it, so `*iter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a vector of pointers to objects.

When you *iterate* the vector, the object you have "in hand" is an iterator. To go from that iterator to the object in the vector you have to dereference it (the `(*iter)` bit). Now you have a pointer. To go from that to the actual object, you need to also dereference the pointer. That's the last `(*iter)->` bit.